# Mostrar errores en conexión SFTP con PHP

Tags: php, php7, sftp

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión SFTP en mi localhost.
Y al parecer no me aparece nigún tipo de error, pero de igual modo no se si se logro conectar.

La documentación de PHP me da el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
```

A lo cual yo hice la siguiente función dentro de mi objeto ftp()

```
public function cxn() {
     $cxn = ssh2_connect(
         $this->host,
         $this->port
     );
     if(!$cxn) die('bc:e:KTUHMbSz8azyEaZS');
     ssh2_auth_password(
         $cxn,
         $this->user,
         $this->pass
     );
     $sftp = ssh2_sftp($cxn);
     if(!$sftp) die('bc:e:SjB4x9YR29pg6Kjr');
     return $cxn;
}
```

Cabe mencionar que ya previamente testie que los `$this` funcionan y entregan los valores establecidos.

La cuestión es que al momento de cargar, ni me marcar los `die(...)` pero tampoco me sale nada si pongo por ejemplo `echo $sftp` para saber si hay algo ahí.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo saber si logro establecer conexión?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar estas lineas al inicio para habilitar los errores de php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Quizas tambien necesitas instalar esta libreria de php tambien

```
 apt-get install libssh2-php
```

Comment: Le tengo activado los errores, creo que lo que falta es la librería. Estoy en una macbook con el php que trae por default. Se puede instalar?

Comment: si deberia mas no se cual sera el comando compatible en mac